# How to fix "Here is no default audio device configured" speech-to-text

Tags: node.js, windows, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, sox

Am trying to call the speech-to-text api of google console for nodejs and apparently is working, but when i try to run the example provider for [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-speech/tree/master/samples) 
 the example *node MicrophoneStream.js* and doing the installation like this [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries), am having the following error.

> STDERR: sox FAIL sox: Sorry, there is no default audio device configured

i dont really know how to pass the device with arguments and i assuming is the default microphone but not sure cause in some page i found a possible value for this like "AUDIOWAVE", also configured in my system and still not working.

the `recorder` object have a function *record* and i can start the recorder from that passing arguments ( i suppose are passed to *sox* binaries ), like this

```
  .record({
      sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
      threshold: 0, //silence threshold
      recordProgram: 'rec', // Try also "arecord" or "sox"
      silence: '5.0', //seconds of silence before ending
    })
```

so i try to pass the *STDERR* argument cause i though was the default device parameter but dont work.

anyway if somebody can help i will gratefully and also if can share with me a documentation reference for all the possibles *.record* arg and description that's gonna be great.
thanks.

here is the complete trace

```
record Started recording +0ms
  record { sampleRate: 16000,
  record   channels: 1,
  record   compress: false,
  record   threshold: 0,
  record   thresholdStart: null,
  record   thresholdEnd: null,
  record   silence: '5.0',
  record   recorder: 'sox',
  record   endOnSilence: false,
  record   audioType: 'wav',
  record   sampleRateHertz: 16000,
  record   STDERR: '2- USB2.0 MIC',
  record   recordProgram: 'rec' } +2ms
  record  sox --default-device --no-show-progress --rate 16000 --channels 1 --encoding signed-integer --bits 16 --type wav - +10ms
Listening, press Ctrl+C to stop.
  record STDERR: sox FAIL sox: Sorry, there is no default audio device configured
  record  +131ms
  record Recording ended +2ms
sox has exited with error code 1.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well i see the question dont get any answer, but i apologize because i found a solution few months ago.

In resumen the version **14.4.2** of sox have some issues in my **windows 10** OS, *(i test in linux version with fedora **30.1** distribution and works correctly)*, so i found a solution in the **node-speakable** repo, just downgrading the version to **14.4.1**.

> I solved this problem by installing sox 14.4.1 rather than 14.4.2 ([here](https://github.com/sreuter/node-speakable/issues/18#issuecomment-226675582))

i solved this problem in the same way.

anyway ([there](https://github.com/sreuter/node-speakable/issues/18#issuecomment-261863671)) is another way in the same post who can solved with the version 14.4.2, but i think is a little tricky cause you play with the command and not implement the library or scripts files but is still a option.